# print rich text box in a specific tab multiple pages C#

Tags: c#, winforms, printdocument, printdialog

I am doing a web browser with multiple tabs and each tab probably will have a new website differs from the other tabs.
now what i am trying to do is to print the page on a specific tab and the page might consists of multiple pages when i am trying to print.
this is my code and the problem with the code is it is only printing one page and on the last tab had been opened. any suggestions:

```
  //this is the printDocemnt from the toolbox
  private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        Font font1 = new Font("Arial", 16, FontStyle.Regular);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(rtb.Text, font1, Brushes.Black, 100, 100);//rtb.Text is a richtextbox object that i initialize in the beginning of the form

    }

    //this is the printbutton just a normal button
    private void PrintButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        printDialog1.ShowDialog();
        printDocument1.Print();
    }
```

Comment: If you're using a standard browser type object it should have its own print methods.

Comment: How can you have *one* RichTextBox for a program that supports *multiple* instances of a web browser?  How is the RTB even related to the browsers?

Comment: I am getting sending an http request and retrieve data as html code i am not using the rendering or webbroswer tool and the rich text box is created on each new tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i did it: the Print document contains this code:

```
        private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        Font font1 = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular);
        //e.Graphics.DrawString(tabsProperties[tabsProperties.IndexOf(new TabProperties(this.tabControl1.SelectedIndex))].TabHtml, font1, Brushes.Black, 100, 100);



        int charactersOnPage = 0;
        int linesPerPage = 0;

        // Sets the value of charactersOnPage to the number of characters 
        // of stringToPrint that will fit within the bounds of the page.
        e.Graphics.MeasureString(stringToPrint, font1,
            e.MarginBounds.Size, StringFormat.GenericTypographic,
            out charactersOnPage, out linesPerPage);

        // Draws the string within the bounds of the page
        e.Graphics.DrawString(stringToPrint, font1, Brushes.Black,
            e.MarginBounds, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);

        // Remove the portion of the string that has been printed.
        stringToPrint = stringToPrint.Substring(charactersOnPage);

        // Check to see if more pages are to be printed.
        e.HasMorePages = (stringToPrint.Length > 0);

    }
```

this is the print button:

```
   private void PrintButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        stringToPrint = tabsProperties[tabsProperties.IndexOf(new TabProperties(this.tabControl1.SelectedIndex))].TabHtml;

        printDialog1.ShowDialog();
        printDocument1.Print();

    }
```